# Make Properties visible from outside the class VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a Window that I need to do some work on, and a class that will do some routine work, say open a FileDialog. I need to be able to assign properties to the class, so when I dimensionalize the class, I assign a specific property that should be taken into account as the code runs.

For example:

```
Dim ofd as new OpenFileDialog
ofd.Image
ofd.Open()
```

ofd.Image, where "Image" is a predefined property that is accesible to the programer from the main Window. Then as i call ofd.Open(), it should know that it has been assigned an Image Property and run the code accordingly.

I have looked everywhere for a solution, but maybe I don't know how to call it. If anyone can help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: These classes are sealed (aka NotInheritable), you cannot inherit from them and add new properties.  Use encapsulation instead.

Comment: And if in Winforms, which I think it sounds like, a user control would help provide this encapsulation and re-usability to boot

Comment: its actually wpf, but no problems. I'll search encapsulation. thanks!